# 18.04 fresh install login loop, no mouse, slow keyboard input, geForce gtx 1060

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, login

I've just bought a new PC:

- ASRock H370M-ITX/ac 1151-2 Mini-ITX Motherboard
- Intel Core i5 8600 Hex Core LGA 1151-2 3.10 GHz CPU Processor
- MSI GeForce GTX 1060 6GT OCV2 6GB Video Card

Ubuntu installed from ISO. At first login screen I have the following symptoms:

- Mouse cursor is visible but unresponsive.
- Keyboard input is extremely delayed (~5 seconds per key press).
- After inputting password and pressing enter, the screen goes black, some text is printed, then it returns to the login screen (login loop).

I've disabled secure boot and used legacy boot to no avail.

Please help!

Comment: Disabling Secure Boot should be OK, legacy definitely not OK. Always use UEFI mode for current hardware. Because you have a new(ish) Nvidia card you may need `nomodeset` to boot a graphical session and then install Nvidia drivers (or do it from a TTY).

Answer (score 0):

I switched primary graphics card to the integrated gpu and was able to boot. From here I was able to install proprietary nVidia drivers.

After switching back to nVidia card everything working great.